# Devise, where to add a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to add a timeoutable model to devise after my initial configuration.

I enabled the config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.timeout_in = 30.minute
```

But where do I actually add the `devise :timeoutable` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you install devise you need to configure model using built in generator

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

example rails generate devise User. See this section

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#user-content-getting-started

Once you have that inside app/models/user.rb you can add desired modules

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :timeoutable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :confirmable
end
```

Hope it helps